# SceneDelegate casting failed when connected on UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor

Tags: swiftui

**App:**

```
@main
struct MarqueViewApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) private var appDelegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

**AppDelegate:**

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        print("App delegate init!")
        return true
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
          let sceneConfig: UISceneConfiguration = UISceneConfiguration(name: nil, sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
          sceneConfig.delegateClass = SceneDelegate.self
          return sceneConfig
      }
    
}
```

**SceneDelegate:**

```
class SceneDelegate: NSObject, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    
    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        print("SceneDelegate is connected!")
    }
}
```

**ContentView onAppear:**

```
.onAppear {
        if let sceneDelegate = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first?.delegate as? SceneDelegate {
            print("SCENE DELEGATE FOUND")
        } else {
            print("SCENE DELEGATE NOT FOUND")
        }
    }
```

It's my console output:

```
App delegate init!
SceneDelegate is connected!
SCENE DELEGATE NOT FOUND
```

Why I got "SCENE DELEGATE NOT FOUND" instead of "SCENE DELEGATE FOUND"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SwiftUI cannot let you *completely* replace the scene delegate with your own class. You are not the only one that wants to implement `UISceneDelegate` methods. SwiftUI also needs to implement some of the methods to work correctly! Of course, this applies to the `UIApplicationDelegate` as well.

`UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor` doesn't actually change `UIApplication.shared.delegate` or `connectedScenes.first?.delegate`. These delegates will be something that SwiftUI controls. SwiftUI just *forwards* the delegate method calls to your own class.

[image]

As you can clearly see from the memory graph here, the `delegate` of the `UIWindowScene` is an instance of `AppSceneDelegate` - an internal type in SwiftUI. This instance has a `sceneDelegateBox` property that stores a `FallbackDelegateBox`, and your `SceneDelegate` is in this box.

As a proof of concept, you can read off the names of the properties in the memory graph, and access your delegate using a `Mirror`:

```
let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first!.delegate!)
let delegate = mirror.descendant("sceneDelegateBox", "some", "storage", "instance") as! SceneDelegate
```

That said, this is SwiftUI's internal implementation details, and probably will break in the future. If you need your scene delegate for some reason, you should find some other way to achieve your goal that does not involve getting the scene delegate.

Comment: Intersting, So do you have any idea to achieve the scene delegate?

Comment: @Vahid *why* do you need access you the scene delegate in the first place? You can probably achieve your ultimate goal using  a SwiftUI API instead, or at least a way that doesn’t involve accessing the scene delegate. I.e. this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I actually need to present a view over all screens, also sheets. I setup my presenter view on SceneDelegate, So I need SceneDelegate to show / hide my view.

Comment: I didn't find any API to present view over sheets too from. presenting view should be started from one place (ContentView for exam) and I can't handle all sheets to overlay it or ZStack it. Also I have to keep user to the what ever screen after dismissing this presented view.

Comment: @Vahid that can be posted as a new question. Explain what you want to do clearly, and remember to include a [mcve] to show how you cannot do this in pure SwiftUI. That said, it sounds like you are trying to present sheets from a centralised place, which goes against the design of SwiftUI. Consider also explaining why you are doing *that* too.